# Running Javascript in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Loading animation does not work in Javascript code, I tried many methods unfortunately did not work.

Animation runs smoothly on JSFiddle. [Loading animated demo on JSFiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/emresaracoglu/c78vF/828/)

```
$.getJSON('/post', function (data) {
        document.getElementById('table').innerHTML = "";
        var tbs = $("#table");
        $.each(data.data, function (i, mod) {
            loadingAni(4000); // 4 sec
            tbs.append('<tr><td><div id="myDivId"><div class="progress"></div><div class="content">Loading</div></div></tr>');
        });
 });


function loadingAni($time) {
    $('.progress').animate({width: '100%'}, $time);
};
```

Where do I make mistakes?

Comment: `$.getJSON(/post',` should be `$.getJSON('/post',`

Comment: You are missing a quote here `$.getJSON(/post'`.Not sure if this is just typo

Comment: Also, it looks like you're making a variable 'tb' but then trying to append to 'tbs'...I am guessing you want to append to 'tb'?

Comment: I removed the address before I write the question, thanks :) @dave

Comment: Yes, I changed but still not working @jdgower

Comment: Explain what you mean by "not working" please. What errors are you getting in the console?

Comment: Does not write any errors on the console. @j08691

Comment: Why are you calling loadingAni which looks for a div with a class of progress before you even add that div to the DOM?

Comment: The fiddle doesn't load for me (or its blank)

Comment: Because I give time @JoshMein

Comment: Try check [link](http://fiddle.jshell.net/emresaracoglu/c78vF/828/) @Amy

Comment: @Bekle that's the same link.  Why would it be any different?  And no, it still doesn't work for me.

Comment: You need to add more details like what's the JSON (data) structure. Did the GET call even return proper JSON? Also as @JoshMein says, is the progress div present when you call the function? You seem to add it only after the call..

Comment: @Amy [link](http://fiddle.jshell.net/emresaracoglu/c78vF/824/)

Comment: @Vasan I can get data with JSON, no problem. Just the animation does not work.

Comment: Why don't you update/edit your question passing all those information you are posting in the comments and more details, to avoid spamming the comments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem is that you are calling your `loadingAni()` before the div it is searching for has even been added to the DOM. Since there is no element with a class of progress yet, the animate cannot be applied to anything. You are also calling loadingAni more than once so it will setup the progress bar more than once if there are multiple rows since it adds the animate to all elements with a class of progress even though some may already have it. IMHO, You need to move the `loadingAni()` below the appending of the progress div or even better move it outside of the each loop altogether.

```
$.each(data.data, function (i, mod) {
    tbs.append('<tr><td><div id="myDivId"><div class="progress"></div><div class="content">Loading</div></div></tr>');
});

loadingAni(4000); // 4 sec
```

Comment: You are a different person in this life.They gave me a votedown and they constantly criticize rather than the solution. But you reached the solution for me. Thank you man for your time.